# how to read text file sentence by sentence in perl?

Tags: perl

i want to read from text file sentence by sentence. my problem is that the code below only separate based on period.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "data.txt";
open (FILE , $file);
my @buffer;
$/ = '.';  
while ( my $sentence = <FILE> ) {
#do_something
}
close FILE;
```

is there anyway to make `$/` take regex like this `/[.?!]/` so it separates sentences based on question mark or exclamation mark and not only period

Comment: See also [`Lingua::Sentence`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::Sentence)

Comment: $/ is a string and can't be used as a regex. "Remember: the value of $/ is a string, not a regex. awk has to be better for something. :-)" From: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: What do you want to happen for the following sentence: `"'How often do you come here?', asked Mr. Smith."`

Comment: @SinanÜnür it actually a whole sentence ,but i will argue that it is not happened more often. i know that  `.?!` not always a true  end for sentence but at least 80% of text file has sentences end with these `.?!` characters

Comment: @HåkonHægland you should write up an answer with Lingua::Sentence. It's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done more properly using [`Lingua::Sentence`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::Sentence) :

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Lingua::Sentence;

my $fn = "data.txt";
open (my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $str = do {local $/; <$fh>};
close $fh;

for my $sentence (Lingua::Sentence->new("en")->split_array( $str)) {
    say $sentence;
}
```

With **data.txt**:

```
'How often do you come here?', asked Mr. Smith.
This is a paragraph. It contains several sentences. "But why," you ask?
```

we get the following output:

```
'How often do you come here?', asked Mr. Smith.
This is a paragraph.
It contains several sentences.
"But why," you ask?
```