# Extracting sentences by matching dictionary words

Tags: perl

I have a lot of strings but contain words or phrases of interest. For example:
'I like the cherry blossoms when spring is here and I love to click photos for the same '

contains the words/phrases of interest  "cherry blossoms", "love" and "click ".

My job is to find out the sentences with the words/phrases of interest .And if possible score each string so that strings that are composed of two or more words/phrases get a better score than strings that have lower count.

Is this a job for recursive descent parsing, or is there a faster way to be doing this? For this task, I am willing to trade off a little speed for accuracy.

My dictionary is going to consist of about 250,000 words. I can store them on the disk in any fashion I want. Is there any kind of format (perhaps some db file format) that would lend itself well to the kind of lookups that I am going to need to be doing?

Is there a CPAN module that would be a good fit for me? Or is there a simple solution .

Thanks

Comment: How do you distinguish between sentences? See also [How to read text file sentence by sentence in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42754472/2173773)

Comment: For each sentence you might be able to search for words using an assembled regex. See for example [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble)

Comment: That sounds like you could just shove all the phrases into a regex and count the matches.

Answer (score 2):

Search for natural language processing (NLP) on cpan; e.g. [Lingua::EN::*](https://metacpan.org/search?size=500&q=Lingua%3A%3AEN&search_type=modules)

Also search for 'bag of words' online/journals for an intro to the field.